# Install the full text search to an application running on SQL Server 2005 express

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-express

I have an application running on mssql 2005 express and I want to install the full text search.

What should I do?

Can I download the full text search service and install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

To use Full Text Search you'll need [SQL Server 2005 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4C6BA9FD-319A-4887-BC75-3B02B5E48A40&displaylang=en). If you previously installed Express (standard), then (sadly) it isn't as simple as running the Advanced installer and adding Full-Text Search option to your existing install.

The error I got was:

> Reason: Your upgrade is blocked. For
>   more information about upgrade
>   support, see the "Version and Edition
>   Upgrades" and "Hardware and Software
>   Requirements" topics in SQL Server
>   2005 Setup Help or SQL Server 2005
>   Books Online.
>
> Build version check:
>
> Your upgrade is blocked because the
>   existing component is a later version
>   than the version you are trying to
>   upgrade to. To modify an existing SQL
>   Server component, go to Add or Remove
>   Programs in Control Panel, select the
>   component you would like to modify,
>   and then click Change/Remove.

There appears to be two solutions:

1. Backup and detach your existing
   databases and uninstall SQL Server
   2005 Express. Then install SQL
   Server 2005 Express with Advanced
   Service (select Full Text Search as
   an option). Then re-attach all of
   your databases.
2. Run the Advanced installer and choose
   a new instance name. You'll have two
   instances of SQL Express running,
   but if it is for development
   purposes then it shouldn't be a big
   problem. This would be the fastest
   route to getting up and running with
   full-text search.

The following pages might also help:

1. [Upgrading to SQL Server 2005
   Express with Advanced Services](http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/50173/sql_server_50173.html)
2. [SQL Server 2005 Express with the
   Full-Text option greyed out](http://www.intraspin.com/webstrategyblog/sql-server-2005-express-full-text-search-greyed-out)

**If you are going to choose the first path, then I would choose to install [SQL Express 2008 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) instead.**